# C memory allocation and deallocation

Tags: c, memory-management

I have written the following C function that returns a double pointer after necessary memory allocation.

```
// integer double pointer to 2d array
void** idp_to_2d ( int rows , int cols ) {
    int i ;
    void **est = malloc ( rows * sizeof ( int* ) ) ;
    for ( i = 0 ; i <= rows ; i ++ )
        est[i] = malloc ( cols * sizeof (int ) ) ;
    return est ;
}
```

Then I receive this pointer using the following code from `main()`:

```
int **est = ( int** ) idp_to_2d ( rows , cols ) ;
```

It works fine and I can index like `est[i][j]` meaning memory was allocated correctly.

Now I free up the memory in `main()` using the code that follows:

```
int i ;
for ( i = 0 ; i <= rows ; i ++ )
    free ( est[i] ) ;
free ( est ) ;
```

Now I get **double free or corruption** error.

My compiler is **gcc 4.9.2**, **OS** is **Ubuntu 15.04** (64-bit) and I am using **NetBeans IDE 8.0.2**.

Comment: The problem with [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) is that it might *seem* to work okay, and you do have undefined behavior when you go out of bounds of allocated memory.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your for loops are wrong - you are iterating over one too many rows - change:

```
for ( i = 0 ; i <= rows ; i ++ )
               ^^^
```

to:

```
for ( i = 0 ; i < rows ; i ++ )
               ^^^
```

in both the `malloc` loop and the `free` loop.

---

Also, although it's not a bug as such, you should really change:

```
void** idp_to_2d(...
```

to:

```
int** idp_to_2d(...
```

and of course:

```
void **est = malloc(...
```

to:

```
int **est = malloc(...
```

since the function returns an `int **` not a `void **`. (There really is no point in using `void **` in any of your code.)

You can also drop the redundant (and potentially dangerous) cast of the return value, so:

```
int **est = ( int** ) idp_to_2d ( rows , cols ) ;
```

would just be:

```
int **est = idp_to_2d ( rows , cols ) ;
```

Comment: "*You would then not need to cast the return value*" the OP still needs to cast inside the function when doing the `return`. To get around all this castings, inside the function `void **est ` addtionally should be changed to `int **est`.

Comment: Alternativly the function could be defined to just return `void*`.

Comment: @PaulR edited as instructed and got the same error. please have another look over the post.

Comment: @ashubuntu: please don't edit the code in the question - it makes a nonsense of the answers for future readers. You probably have some other bug in between the allocation and freeing - try to track this down and if you are still stuck then post a new question with the latest code.

Comment: I would also go so far as to mention that he's not checking for a `NULL` return from `malloc`